# Java "Null, The class ends at Null"

Tags: java, class, null

I'm very new to programming, and this code is far from complete so excuse the amateur-ness.

this code is to add time onto a running time through use of multiple classes

Here is my Time Class:

```
public  class Time {

private int Minutes, Hours, TotalMin;
private String stringAM= "AM", stringPM = "PM", correctedMinutes ;
public String valid, TimeofDay;
public static int error;
public Object toString;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Sets up the time by defining its minutes and hours 




    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
public  Time(int  hours, int minutes)
    { if (minutes>59|| minutes<0|| hours>23 || hours<0) {
       Hours=0;
       Minutes=0;
          error=1;
          return;
          }
      else {Hours=hours;
            Minutes=minutes; 
            error=0;
            return;
      }}

public int Time2(int minutes, int hours) {
         if (Hours<12 || Hours>0 || TimeofDay.equals ("AM") || TimeofDay.equals ("PM")) {
               Hours=0;
               Minutes=0;
                  return error=0;

                      }
              else { 
                  Hours=hours;
                    Minutes=minutes;
                     return error=0;
                  }
            }

    public int addMinutes (int Hours, int Minutes, int elapsedMin)
    { 
        if (elapsedMin<0)
        return error=1;

            else {
            TotalMin=elapsedMin+Minutes;
                    return error=0;}
        }{

    while (TotalMin>60)
            {TotalMin=TotalMin-60;
            Hours=Hours+1;   if (Hours==25)
             { Hours=0;
             Minutes=TotalMin;
             }
    }
        public String toString ()
        {
            String correctedMinutes = String.format("%02d", Minutes);
            return Hours+ ":" + correctedMinutes + ":" + TimeofDay;     }


}
```

I also have some test code

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class TimeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
int minutes, hours; 
String TimeofDay;
Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter starting hour:");
hours=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter starting minute:");
minutes=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter AM or PM:");
TimeofDay=scan.next();

Time classtime = new Time (hours, minutes);
{}
classtime.Time2(minutes, hours);


int error=Time.error;
if (error==1)
    System.out.println("This is an invalid time");

System.out.println (classtime.toString);
System.out.print("The class ends at ");
System.out.println (classtime.toString);

    }}
```

Basically I just cant figure out why when I run my code it does not finish running but instead prints:

```
"Null
 The class ends at Null"
```

Any insight? I realize there are other problems with the code but I will fix those once I can get it to run more

(btw I know the method Time 2 seems very redundant, my teacher is requiring it for class or I would have just included it in the constructor)

any input would be much appreciated

Comment: First, go download an IDE and learn how to use it. Your formatting is extremely hard to read. You have random `{}` in the middle of your code. You aren't following java naming conventions.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `public Object toString;` in your code?

Comment: @RohitJain Likely OP forgot parentheses and blindly clicked the first auto-fix option in his/her IDE.

Comment: O_o Your code, as posted, doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4):

***Don't, please don't*** blindly click the first auto-fix option in your IDE, especially if you don't read or understand it.

toString should be a method of type String, not a field of type Object:

Cut out `Object toString;` in the class. That's not needed.

This is the code you need that calls the `toString` method that returns a string:

```
System.out.println (classtime.toString());
System.out.print("The class ends at ");
System.out.println (classtime.toString());
```

That being said, you do need to better organize and handle your code. Use proper naming conventions and indent/structure it in a readable manner.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know I'm no good at this, I'm literally just beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but just a few tips for readable code:

- Whenever you write a method, after you write the top line of that method, immediately follow that up with setting up your braces and positioning your curser inside.
  So when you do something like

  `public int addMinutes(int hours, int minutes, int elapsedMin)`

then your very next step should be

```
public int addMinutes(int hours, int minutes, int elapsedMin){} //<--these braces
```

then put the curser between and chop the braces down the middle

```
public int addMinutes(int hours, int minutes, int elapsedMin){|}
```

to...

```
public int addMinutes(int hours, int minutes, int elapsedMin){

}
```

and always have the closing brace match up vertically with the first word of the method as it is above. If you get in the habit of always immediately making your braces and chopping them down the middle, it will be so much easier to keep track of your code

- Only indent when you are inside a set of braces

so if you want to put code inside your addMinutes method, you indent all the code inside those braces one indentation level

```
public int addMinutes(int hours, int minutes, int elapsedMin){

    if(elapsedMin < 0)
}
```

and an if statement should have braces. So any code inside THOSE braces should be indented one level further in...

```
public int addMinutes(int hours, int minutes, int elapsedMin){

    if(elapsedMin < 0){
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Notice how the closing brace of the if matches up with the letter i in if and the closing brace of the method matches with the letter p of public.

- You should never see {} in your code on a line all by itself.
- Also you should never see }} in your code on a line all by itself
- Use proper naming conventions. method names should start with a lower case letter. Class names and Constructors start with a capital, so when you declare

  `public int Time2`

it looks like a cross between a constructor for a Time2 object and a method.

Following these conventions will not only make your code much more readable, they will make guys on forums a lot more likely to help you with your issue. If you post a jumbled mess of poorly formatted code, some people won't even take the time to read it.

Here is a great link that can fill in any details, and honestly you could probably read through it in only 5 minutes. It recommends an alternate brace placement convention where everything is the same except the opening brace is placed one line below the method rather than on the same line as the method. Both are acceptable, but in general you should pick one of these two conventions and STRICTLY adhere to it as you code.

http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/index.html